L5R 5e, Use the same Shuji twice
I've encountered a situation where two characters both took the same Earth Shuji, "Touchstone of Courage," and I haven't found any limitations on its use.
For example:

The Crab bushi uses it, giving the party +4 to composure.
The Lion bushi then uses it on his turn, giving the party another +4 to composure.
The whole party now has +8 to composure.

This makes it impossible for a GM to unmask any of the heroes and breaks the intrigue mechanisms of the game.
What have I missed?
Edit: Shuji's description is even more confusing. If I understand it correctly, there is no restriction on a character using it twice or thrice in a row, allowing them to gain infinite composure for the party.


Reddit has found the answer in the Technics chapter, Persistent Effects ruling, page 174, core book: 

it is much prefered to use > quote instead of a text picture.
